# Bookmarklet to control jscontroller

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I use javascript bookmarklets to control window layouts on a page, but one of the elements will be repositioned by another element. If I go into inspect source, I can see the jscontroller attribute for it being set and if I break that link, it functions the way I need it to. However, I'm not sure how to adjust that through a bookmarklet. My usual ones look like this:

```
javascript:(function(){var d=document,e=d.getElementsByClassName("zWfAib")[0];e.style="width: 1280px; height: 720px; left: 16px; top: 16px;";})();javascript:(function(){var d=document,e=d.getElementsByClassName("p2hjYe TPpRNe")[0];e.style="width: 1280px; height: 720px; left: 0px; top: 0px;";})();
```

I've tried changing style to jscontroller and passing a value, but that doesn't adjust it. Is there another way to change this attribute through a bookmarklet?

EDIT: Another approach if it makes a difference, changing the jsaction that element is set to. Is that possible through a bookmarklet?